# SQL Inner Join and Partitioning To obtain RowNumbers when matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have 2 tables. The first table 'a'  the second 'b'.
I am writing a query that grabs every row in table a (there is 33 rows defined) and inner joins table b where the EnclLocation or the BackPanLoc match the Workcell in table A.

I only want a row from table B where they match based off BackPan and EnclLocation but they are not the same records. table b has a few rows of data that is assigned to the same workcell as table a. I am just trying to retrieve those additional rows and partition it.

I attached table a and table b. I also attached the desired results for this query with respect to Workcell 10 only as an example... As you can see, table B has 4 records that has either the EnclLocation or the BackPanLoc = 10. But my results only show the same DelvNumber 4 times. any help is most appreicated.

Table a

[image]

Table b

[image]

Incorrect Results

[image]

Desired Results (showing only Workcell 10 as an example)

```
workcell DelvNumber RowNum


    1   447910-02   1
    2   445710-01   1
    2   445710-01   2
    3   444291-01   1
    3   444291-01   2
    4   447910-03   1
    4   447910-03   2
    5   648020-01   1
    6   647800-02   1
    7   646920-01   1
    7   646920-01   2
    8   644830-4-8  1
    8   644830-4-8  2
    9   443990-01   1
    10  645960-01-03    1
    10  445710-11   2
    10  445710-02   3
    10  445710-09   4
```

Code Used

```
WITH ss 
     AS (SELECT a.*, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY a.workcell 
                    ORDER BY a.workcell) AS rownum                
         FROM   nwcurrent a 
                INNER JOIN nwdeliverables b 
                        ON b.encllocation = a.workcell 
                            OR b.backpanloc = a.workcell 
         WHERE  ( b.status < 9 
                  AND ( b.encllocation <> 0 
                         OR b.backpanloc <> 0 ) 
                   OR a.delvnumber = '123' )) 
SELECT * 
FROM   ss
```

copy and paste format

1   447910-02   1
2   445710-01   1
2   445710-01   2
3   444291-01   1
3   444291-01   2
4   447910-03   1
4   447910-03   2
5   648020-01   1
6   647800-02   1
7   646920-01   1
7   646920-01   2
8   644830-4-8  1
8   644830-4-8  2
9   443990-01   1
10  645960-01-03    1
10  445710-11   2
10  445710-02   3
10  445710-09   4

SQLFiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8682/4

Comment: If it is only to find those with RowNum being >1 then you can souround your "SELECT * FROM ss" with "SELECT tbl.* FROM(Your Select) WHERE tbl.RowNum>1. But it's not that simple probably.. I do not understand the desired result: What is wrong with 10 what is not with 8?

Comment: I am just using 10 as an example of what I am trying to return. I have 4 different rows in my desired results for 10, but my incorrect table shows 4 of the same rows. I need to show all row numbers not just rows being >1

Comment: OK, I see... the result for 10 is not wrong, as there is e.g "445710-09" in row 15. But you wanted to see the other reference. Could you please provide your sample data in a copy'n'pasteable format?

Comment: not sure if this is what you are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new try...

```
SELECT a.workcell
      ,a.DelvNumber AS A_DelvNumber
      ,b.DelvNumber AS B_DelvNumber
      ,CASE WHEN a.DelvNumber<>b.DelvNumber THEN b.DelvNumber ELSE a.DelvNumber END AS DelvNumber_Resolved
      ,Row_number() OVER(partition BY a.workcell ORDER BY a.workcell) AS rownum
FROM NWCurrent a 
    INNER JOIN NWDeliverables AS b ON b.EnclLocation=a.WorkCell OR b.BackPanLoc=a.WorkCell 
WHERE (b.status <9 AND (b.EnclLocation<>0 OR b.BackPanLoc<>0)OR a.DelvNumber='123')
```

Comment: No, I do want 445710..... This is in my desired results..... Look at my incorrect results table.   I have 4 of the same rows for workcell 10.... My desired has 4 different rows for workcell 10. I need those 4 different rows

Comment: So, once again: In your desired results you do NOT want to see WorkCells with only one appearance (like 6), you do NOT want to see WorkCells with many appearances as long as their DelvNumber is equal. You only want to see the WorkCell 10, because it has more than one row but differing DelvNumbers.

Comment: making a sqlfiddle to help explain better... almost done

Comment: Workcell 10 appears 4 times in the result.... but the delvnumber is the same for all 4 rows.... this is incorrect.  table b has 3 rows with the encllocation or the backpanloc = the a.workcell.... i want those 3 different delvnumbers as well.  i want all 4 rows, or 3 rows, or 2 or 1... if there is more than one row with different delvnumbers but assigned to the same workcell... i want it... does this help?

Comment: @ENGR024, is there any logic to decide, when to take A_DelvNumber and when the other?

Comment: @Shnugo-- didnt really incorporate any logic to decide. I think I need all A_DelvNumber and only the B_DelvNumber when the workcells match and A_<>B_DelvNumber. I tried that query specifically, but no luck

Comment: @ENGR024, please look at the DelvNumber_Resolved column. I tried to reflect to your logic. But this will always be equal with B_DelvNumber...

Comment: @ENGR024, I think, the missing step is in the new CASE WHEN part somewhere behind the a.DelvNumber<>b.DelvNumber. There must be some " AND ..." this thing I did not get... Anyway, have to finish... Please vote up and or mark as accepted if helpful. We are all hungry for reputation points :-)

Comment: Almost,,,,,,, when we add the B_DelvNumber a few rows become missing......... 31 and 32 Workcells are gone now